# openshift jetpack issue: request timed out

Tags: wordpress, openshift, jetpack

I can't enable [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/) for a Wordpress site hosted on [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/).

I have installed the plugin, created an account on *Wordpress.com* but the plugin can't communicate properly with my application.

When I click on the Jetpack Debug button, it says the request timed out.

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a small gear? You might try using this kb article (https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1082-how-to-check-for-memory-limit-violations) to see if it's a memory issue.

Comment: Hi, I have checked that this is not a memory issue. Someone of openshift did test on his machine/blog and got the same result.

Comment: I have contacted Jetpack and here is there answer: _"It looks like the issue is that your host limits the PHP processes on your server. You should get in touch with them and ask them if their `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN` is set to one and, if it is, ask them to set it to two or higher."_. Please update the parameter :p